# Is There a Way to Always have a Place Widget Relative to Another Widget(Such as Pack)

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, resize, frame

So, I'm using the place method to have a widget overlap other widgets, but its position is relative (with `winfo`) to a widget that uses pack. When the parent frame is resized, the pack position will change, but the place position will not.
This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x300")

search = Entry(root)
search.pack()

search.update()
x = search.winfo_x()
y = search.winfo_y()
width = search.winfo_width()
height = search.winfo_height()

frame = LabelFrame(root, width=width, height=200)
frame.place(x=x, y=y+height)

root.mainloop()
```

The LabelFrame stays in its x and y position when the window is resized. The Entry widget will be used as a search bar and I want autocompletion under it. There will be widgets under the entry widget and the autocompletion will only appear when you are typing (That's not what I'm looking for though. Its just more exposition if you need it). So, is there a way to have the place widget always be relative to the pack widget.  If you have any answers, thank you:)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking; the title and the last sentence ask two completely different questions. Also, are you aware that `place` supports relative placement?

Comment: @BryanOakley The title and last sentence are different questions because I thought both would have viable answers (hence I wrote "My question might not hold the best answer"). I'm sorry if it was unclear. Also, I wasn't aware of relative placement for pack, but how would you do that? I was using winfo for relative placement.

Comment: No, there's no relative placement for `pack`, but there is for `place`. It would help if you could [edit]  your question to include a [mcve]. Just saying you want a widget to be relative to another could be answered in many different ways.

Comment: Pack is not my problem, pack is perfectly fine. It's the place. But would I have to do It manually? I wouldn't be able to have it relative to another widget?

Comment: And I'll create a minimal reproducible example now.

Comment: I know pack isn't your problem. Your earlier comment says "I wasn't aware of relative placement for pack". I was correcting you because there is no relative placement for pack.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thank you for the correction. Also, I've created a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: It's still unclear what you want. You can use pack to put `frame` immediately under `search`. Why do you think you need to use `place`? The problem with answering vague questions about layout is that layout depends a lot on what else is going on in the window. If these are the only two widgets, there's simply no reason to use `place` unless your goal is to make the code as complicated as possible.

Comment: @BryanOakley I edited the question so that it's more clear on what I want. But that's not my question, I know how to do that.

Comment: Use `relx` and `rely` instead of `x` and `y`. Then you need to change the values to be between 0 and 1, where 0 is the far-left/top and 1 is the far-right/bottom, respectively. You will also have to mess with `anchor`. as an example ...`relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor='center')` would put your widget dead center of the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to put one widget relative to another, `place` lets you do that. It's great for things like tooltips or other transient widgets that don't otherwise fit into a normal layout.

The easiest way to do that is to make the widget a child of the controlling widget. For example, for your frame to be placed relative to the search box you can make it a child of the search box. If it's inconvenient to do that, you can use the `in_` parameter to tell `place` which widget is the other widget.

For example, to place your labelframe immediately below the search box and with the same width as the search box you might do it something like this:

```
frame.place(
    in_=search,
    bordermode="outside",
    anchor="nw",
    relx=0,
    rely=1.0,
    y=5,
    relwidth=1.0
)
```

This is what the options mean:

- `in_=search`: place the frame relative to the search box
- `bordermode="outside"`: relative measurements are from the outside of the border (default is "inside")
- `anchor="nw"`: place the widget so that the northwest corner of the frame is at the computed coordinate
- `relx=0`: place the anchor point 0% from the left edge of the search box
- `rely=1.0`: place the frame at 100% of the height of the search box
- `y=5`: add 5 pixels to the computed position so it floats just a little below the window
- `relwidth=1.0`: make the width of the frame 100% the width of the search box.

Obviously you don't have to use `y=5`, I just added it to illustrate the additive behavior of using `rely` and `y`.