# How do I find the position of a widget relative to the window in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, window, position

I need to find the position of a widget relative to the **window**.

winfo_x returns the position relative to the widgets parent, this is a problem if the widget is in a frame.

winfo_rootx returns the position relative to the screen, not the window.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this? It's just a matter of a little math, but with so few details it makes me wonder if there's a better way to solve your problem than to compute the position of a widget relative to the window.

Comment: I need to place a frame under a button no matter where I position it.

Comment: What was that little math you mentioned? I'm stumped

Comment: You already know the meaning of `.winfo_rootx()`, I wonder why you cannot figure out the *little math* yourself: `<widget>.winfo_rootx() - <window>.winfo_rootx()`.

Comment: If you need to put a frame below another "no matter what", the right solution is to use `place` with relative coordinates. If you update your question to reflect what you're really trying to do, I can show you. First, though, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63625317/7432) which gives an example of relative placement.

Comment: Thank you acw1668, that is all I needed to know.